# npm references in Visual Studio 2017: how to deal with "exclamation - not-istalled"

Tags: visual-studio, npm, visual-studio-2017

Situation:

[image]

I have tried:

```
 1. "VS/Solution Explorer/npm/context-right-click-menu/Restore Packages.."

 2. npm install

 3. npm install kind-of (concreate not installed package)
```

nothing helps.

Actually I'm not suffer from it, but feel I need to know what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`npm init` fix this and other asterix problems (together or without `del npm_modules`, `npm istall`).

I do not know why we should time to time repeat `npm init` but this works.